# How can I create a list with N objects?

Tags: java, list, collections, java-8

I am trying to create a list of objects with n elements. I am trying to do this in the most java 8 way as possible. Something similar to the question asked for c# here :
[Creating N objects and adding them to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122528/creating-n-objects-and-adding-them-to-a-list)

Something like this:

```
List <Objects> getList(int numOfElements)
{

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you tried ?

Comment: What actually you want to achieve?

Comment: Are you seriously trying to close the question within 2 minutes of its being posted?

Comment: @Guy it is in C# :D

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If I got your question right:

```
List <Object> getList(int numOfElements){
     return IntStream.range(0, numOfElements)
              .mapToObj(Object::new) // or x -> new Object(x).. or any other constructor 
              .collect(Collectors.toList()); 
}
```

If you want the same object n times:

```
Collections.nCopies(n, T)
```

Comment: I found I didn't up it... make up it. :)

Comment: `Collections.nCopies(n, T)`
will return an immutable `List<T>`

If you need to get an editable `List<T>` you should create an empty List and than call addAll passing the result of nCopies

`List<T> temp = new ArrayList<>();
temp.addAll(Collections.nCopies(n, T));
return temp;`

Comment: A shorter version of @afj88's answer: ```return new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(n, T));```

Answer (score 47):

You could use `Stream.generate(Supplier<T>)` in combination with a reference to a constructor and then use `Stream.limit(long)` to specify how many you should construct:

```
Stream.generate(Objects::new).limit(numOfElements).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

At least to me, this is more readable and illustrates intent much more clearly than using an `IntStream` for iteration does as e.g. [Alberto Trindade Tavares suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45275624/1391325).

If you want something which performs better in terms of complexity and memory usage, pass the result size to `Stream.collect(Collector<? super T,A,R>)`:

```
Stream.generate(Objects::new).limit(numOfElements).collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new ArrayList<>(numOfElements)));
```

Comment: while correct, note that this will parallelize worse then a `IntStream` approach - because this is still an infinite stream (limit will not introduce the `SIZED` property); otherwise +1 from me.

Comment: @Eugene: if you want maximum parallel performance, you should use `Arrays.asList(IntStream.range(0, numOfElements) .mapToObj(Objects::new) .toArray(Objects[]::new));`

Comment: @Holger I assume that has to do with underneath Spliterators? And `ArraySpliterator` would be better than `RangeIntSpliterator`?

Comment: @Eugene: no, you have the same spliterator in both cases, as the source is still a range. But `toArray` with a (sub)sized stream will allocate the final array immediately and let each thread write into the right part of that array, in contrast to `collect(Collectors.toList())` which collects into local lists and needs additional merging steps. Also, the lists used by `toList()` may need (multiple) capacity increase operations. See also [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782165/why-didnt-stream-have-a-tolist-method#comment45848538_28782165)

Comment: I would say that we can custom our object by calling its constructor i.e `Stream.generate(() -> new SomeClassName(someValue_01, ... , someValue_N))
                .limit(size)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());` Or even we can pass through and custom _supplier_ to make the generation

Answer (score 6):

An equivalent implementation of the C# code you mentioned in Java 8, with `streams`, is the following (EDIT to use mapToObj, suggested by @Eugene):

```
List <Objects> getList(int numOfElements)
{
  return IntStream.range(0, numOfElements)
                  .mapToObj(x -> new Objects())
                  .collect(Collectors.toList()); 
}
```

Comment: Messed up a little. Map that should be used here.

Comment: I'm also not quite sure but i think he wants to send some param to the object constructor that he is creating - at least the `x`, so it looks like it should be `.map(x -> new Objects(x))` or better `.map(Objects::new)`

Comment: OP didn't make clear. If he wants to use x as parameter for constructor, your answer is the best one (have upvoted that)

Answer (score 3):

Why not keep it simple?? If you want to use LINQ or a Lambda it definetly is possible but the question is if it is more readable or maintainable.

```
List <Objects> getList(int numOfElements)
{
  List<Objects> objectList = new LinkedList<>();
  for(int i = 0; i <= numOfElements; i++)
  {
    objectList.add(new Object());
  }
  return objectList;
}
```

If you insist this can be the lambda:

```
  return IntStream.range(0, numOfElements)
                  .mapToObj(x -> new Objects())
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Creds to @Alberto Trindade since he posted it faster than me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I prefer the more old-school approach myself. But using Java8ified solution is a requirement :(

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind a third-party dependency, the following will work with [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections):

```
List<Object> objects = Lists.mutable.withNValues(10, Object::new);
Verify.assertSize(10, objects);
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.