# The entire ArrayList is updating when I am trying to update one element Java 21

Tags: java, arraylist

I was doing some algo in my free time and had a weird issue. I can not understand why this is happening. I have two lists, and I am updating elements precisely the same way in both of them, but in the "lazy" list, when I update an element, all elements are updated.

This is the essential part of the code:

```java
public class SegmentTree {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> a = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
        SegmentTreeObject segmentTreeObject = new SegmentTreeObject(a);
        segmentTreeObject.build(a);
        segmentTreeObject.list.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.leftPosition + " " + s.rightPosition + " " + s.value));
        segmentTreeObject.updateLazy(new Point(0, 7), 5);
        segmentTreeObject.lazy.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.leftPosition + " " + s.rightPosition + " " + s.value));
    }
}

class SegmentTreeObject {

    List<Node> list;
    List<Integer> original;

    //Lazy tree
    List<Node> lazy;

    int size;

    SegmentTreeObject(List<Integer> obj) {
        this.list = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(4 * obj.size(), new Node(100, 100, 0)));
        this.lazy = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(4 * obj.size(), new Node(0, 0, 0)));
        this.original = new ArrayList<>(obj);
        this.size = obj.size();
    }

    void updateLazyTree(int start, int end, int left, int right, int node, int newValue) {
        if(left > end || right < start) {
            return;
        }
        if (start >= left && end <= right) {
            this.list.get(node).updateNode(this.list.get(node).value + (end-start+1) * newValue);
            this.lazy.get(2 * node + 1).updateNode(this.lazy.get(2*node+1).value + newValue);
            this.lazy.get(2 * node + 2).updateNode(this.lazy.get(2*node+2).value + newValue);

            return;
        }

        int mid = start + (end-start) / 2;
        updateLazyTree(start, mid, left, right, 2 * node + 1, newValue);
        updateLazyTree(mid + 1, end, left, right, 2 * node + 2, newValue);
    }

    void updateLazy(Point range, int value) {
        updateLazyTree(0, this.size - 1, range.x, range.y, 0, value);
    }
}

class Node {
    int leftPosition;
    int rightPosition;
    int value;

    // All-args constructor omitted for brevity

    public void updateNode(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

and the output of the lazy is like this:

```
0 0 10
0 0 10
0 0 10
0 0 10
0 0 10
0 0 10
0 0 10
```

I have also checked with the debugger, and yes, the "lazy" list is updating the entity after one "updateNode" call.

Thank you for your time!

Please let me know if you have any ideas; I might be wrong in creating the "lazy" list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count the `new`. That's how many objects you have. Thus, in:

```
this.list = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(4*obj.size(),new Node(100,100,0)));
```

I count.. 1 `new`.

So, you have a list with loads of entries, but, **only one `Node` object**. How can that be? How can you have an arraylist whose `.size()` reports, in this example case, 32 (`obj` is 8 big, and you multiply it by 4) - but only one `Node` object?

Well, imagine this situation:

I build one single house.

I then buy an address book from the store. It has 32 pages. On each and every page I write the same address. The address of that one house I built.

TADA! 32 houses!

Not quite. I have 32 addresses, sure. And they are all the same. 1 house, 32 pages.

The same situation is happening here. You have one node object, and an arraylist with 32 references, all to that one node object. Change one and you change them all, for the exact same reason that if you take that address book with its 32 pages, pick a random page, walk over to the house, toss a brick through the window then: Regardless of which page you open your address book to, if you walk over to the address you find there, guess what? Window's broken.

You want 32 node objects.

```
this.list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 4 * obj.size(); i++) this.list.add(new Node(100, 100, 0));
```

If I count the amount of times `new` is executed *now*, I end up at 32. Indeed this code will do fine (you'll also have to fix `this.lazy`, of course).

If you feel that somehow ruins the cleanliness of it all, well, this method COULD exist in `j.u.Collections`:

```
public static <T> nTimes(int n, Supplier<T> supplier) {
  if (n < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("" + n);
  var list = new ArrayList<T>(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) list.add(supplier.get());
  return list;
}
```

Then you could call:

```
Collections.nTimes(4 * obj.size() () -> new Node(100, 100, 0));
```

But that method simply doesn't exist. It may never: In large part, `nCopies` exists at all because it allows quite an impressive optimization: It can represent a million entries with virtually no memory, it just remembers **the one reference** as well as the number 'one million'. `nCopies` is like a magic address book that has only 2 pages, so it's very small: one page with a single number on it, and a second page with a single address on it. For all purposes this address book acts like it was a big one (as many pages as that first number), with the same address on each of those pages. That doesn't sound like a very useful address book, and, indeed, `nCopies` is rarely used. But that's what its for. *If* you need this weird 'address book with LOTS of identical entries' thing, `nCopies` is very very good at it.

It's not at all what you want here, though. So, just write a loop, really.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment!

I taught that the 
"this.list = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(4*obj.size(),new Node(100,100,0)));"
will create a new object every time, as you mentioned 32 new houses. I taught that because I used the same logic for the:
"List<Node> list;" and it is working, as you can see in the following example:
"0 7 76
0 3 10
4 7 26
0 1 3
2 3 7
4 5 11
6 7 15
0 0 1
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 3 4
4 4 5
5 5 6
6 6 7
7 7 8
100 100 0
100 100 0
100 100 0..." up to 32.
Now I am a bit confused why it is working in the "list" and now in the "lasy" basically.

Comment: Another option for instantiating the objects would be something like `Arrays.asList(IntStream.range(0, obj.size()*4) .mapToObj(() -> new Node(100,100,0)) .toArray(Node[]::new));` similar to the answers found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45275402/how-can-i-create-a-list-with-n-objects).

Comment: @Al3x4ndru1 Java is in that sense very very simple. The `nCopies` method cannot capture `new Node(100, 100, 0)` and run it more than once. No; that expression is evaluated then and there before `nCopies` is even invoked, and the result of evaluating that expression is passed. `nCopies` can't rerun the expression. At best it can attempt to clone what it gets (but pretty much nothing in the core libraries does that, and nCopies doesn't either). `() -> new Node(100, 100, 0)` is a 'lambda' - it captures 'the idea of doing that', and can be invoked as often as you like.

Comment: @CalvinP strikes me as 'lambda abuse'. The for loop is not larger (unless you ascribe to 'all blocks must be braced', but then.. why aren't your `mapToObj` and co. calls braced, then? If you apply inconsistent style, the problem is your style guide!), and is properly transparent (checked ex, local mutable var, and control flow) whereas the lambda isn't. It adds nothing here. Now, in the `nTimes` example, it _does_ add something useful.

Comment: Thank you, guys. I will be more careful next time.